# how to auto refresh spinnaker pipeline's console output

Tags: pipeline, spinnaker

does anyone know how can I **auto refresh** `spinnaker pipeline's console output AUTOMATICALLY`?

To check latest logs, I have to close and re-open the output manually everytime :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no autorefresh :/ But you could create a GitHuB issue about a feature here...? That would help many...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!
I already saw few others raised an issue but it was auto closed by the bot as no one looked at it.